# WPF MVVM Login Credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM and I am making headway in understanding. There is one issue that has me a bit confused. I have a Login Page with associated ViewModel to log into the application. But, every time I use credentials I know are correct, it comes back with the "Username Incorrect" MessageBox. It should open to the WindowMain window. Perhaps an issue with Textbox binding?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**ObservableObject**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        Debug.Assert(GetType().GetProperty(propName) != null);

        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, string propName)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)expr;
            MemberExpression memberExpr;

            if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
            {
                var unaryExpr = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
                memberExpr = (MemberExpression)unaryExpr.Operand;
            }
            else
            {
                memberExpr = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(memberExpr.Member.Name);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**LoginRelayCommand**

```
public class LoginRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public LoginRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class LoginWindowVM : ObservableObject
{
    private ICommand _submitLoginButton;

    private Textbox1 _textbox1Input;
    private Textbox2 _textbox2Input;

    public ICommand SubmitLoginButton
    {
        get
        {
            if(_submitLoginButton == null)
            {
                _submitLoginButton = new LoginRelayCommand(param => this.SubmitButton(), null);
            }

            return _submitLoginButton;
        }
    }

    public Textbox1 Textbox1Input
    {
        get { return _textbox1Input; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _textbox1Input, value, () => Textbox1Input); }
    }

    public Textbox2 Textbox2Input
    {
        get { return _textbox2Input; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _textbox2Input, value, () => Textbox2Input); }
    }

    public LoginWindowVM() : base()
    {
        _textbox1Input = new Textbox1();
        _textbox2Input = new Textbox2();
    }

    private void SubmitButton()
    {
        MySqlConnection dbConnectionString = new MySqlConnection(@"datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='optest1a1';username=root;password=");
        try
        {
            if (dbConnectionString.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                dbConnectionString.Open();
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users_sw WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConnectionString);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Textbox1Input);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Textbox2Input);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 1)
            {
                WindowMain dashboard = new WindowMain();
                dashboard.Show();
                dbConnectionString.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Is Incorrect");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConnectionString.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <Grid>
    <Label x:Name="lblUsername" Content="Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblPassword" Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Textbox1Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="128,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtPassword" Text="{Binding Textbox2Input, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="128,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
            Command="{Binding SubmitLoginButton}"
            />
</Grid>
```

**View.cs**

```
    public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    private LoginWindowVM _viewModel;

    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new LoginWindowVM();
        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Binding to `TextBox` Text property which expect `string` as a source and you are binding to `Textbox` itself.
just change it to String property:

```
private String_textbox1Input;

public String Textbox1Input
{
    get { return _textbox1Input; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _textbox1Input, value, () => Textbox1Input); }
}
```

*Note: Textbox default binding mode is `TwoWay` setting it explicitly is of no use*

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!